# objc Separating tuples

Tags: objective-c, json, cocoa-touch, tuples

ran into a simple objc problem and need some help. I'm sending a query to a server that gives me back a tuple wrapped in jSON. Just using the dictionary to sort everything out.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
Nodes *node = [Nodes new];
NSDictionary *jsonDict = [node nodeActivityforNode:@"17" withDates:nil and:nil];
NSDictionary *jsonActivityDict = [jsonDict objectForKey:@"activity"];
NSLog(@"activity?: %@", jsonActivityDict);

}
```

and then heres the debug dump

```
activity?: 

(
    (
    "2013-05-21 16:58:32",
    0
),
    (
    "2013-05-21 16:58:15",
    0
),
    (
    "2013-05-21 16:57:59",
    0
),
```

I'm trying to split up the comma separated values so I can put them in individual int and string objects but just cant think of how to get in there. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Why did you include the Python tag?  Do you want to solve your problem in Python?

Comment: I thought it was a python tuple? I know absolutely nothing about python but the backend was written in python and its doing some parsing dance that converts its tuples to the above output.

Comment: As it comes from JSON and since JSON doesn't have a distinction between two different versions of ordered collections (tuples and lists in Python), I guess it won't be tuples.  It might have been tuples on the Python side before they were converted to JSON, but that's now lost in the conversion.  So I guess your question in fact has nothing to do with Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "activity" data looks like an array of arrays, not a dictionary. If you know you will always get three pairs of values and you want those 6 values put into 6 separate variables then you could do this:

```
NSDictionary *jsonDict = [node nodeActivityforNode:@"17" withDates:nil and:nil];
NSArray *jsonActivities = [jsonDict objectForKey:@"activity"];
NSString *date1 = jsonActivities[0][0];
int int1 = [jsonActivities[0][1] intValue];
NSString *date2 = jsonActivities[1][0];
int int2 = [jsonActivities[1][1] intValue];
NSString *date3 = jsonActivities[2][0];
int int3 = [jsonActivities[2][1] intValue];
```

Note that this code will crash if there are less than 3 sets of pairs or if any of those three "pairs" only has one value instead of two.

Comment: thanks! I used this logic to split it up how I needed into two separate arrays. Thanks for the help